# How can I call ExecutionPolicy algorithms in a constexpr context?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, stl-algorithm

I want to call standard library algorithms with the `ExecutionPolicy` for vectorization. At the same time the call should also work in a `constexpr` context. Unfortunately the `ExecutionPolicy` overloads of the algorithms from the standard library are currently not `constexpr`. At compile time, of course, it doesn't matter if vectorization is used. So in this case I just want to call the overload without `ExecutionPolicy`.

This I have implemented as:

```
#include <execution>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Fn, typename ... T>
constexpr decltype(auto) unseq_invoke(Fn&& fn, T&& ... v) {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        return std::invoke(
            std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<T>(v) ...);
    } else {
        return std::invoke(
            std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::execution::unseq, std::forward<T>(v) ...);
    }
}
```

Basically, this also works exactly as it should:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

constexpr bool is_valid_c_str(std::string_view const view) {
    constexpr auto find_wrapper =
        []<typename ... T>(T&& ... v) {
            return std::find(std::forward<T>(v) ...);
        };

    return unseq_invoke(find_wrapper, view.begin(), view.end(), 0) == view.end();
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;
    static constexpr auto a = "valid c_str"sv;
    static constexpr auto b = "invalid\0c_str"sv;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << a << ": " << is_valid_c_str(a) << '\n'
        << b << ": " << is_valid_c_str(b) << '\n';

    static_assert(is_valid_c_str(a));
    static_assert(!is_valid_c_str(b));
}
```

```
valid c_str: true
invalidc_str: false
```

The problem is that I always have to wrap functions like `std::find` in a lambda. If I try to pass it directly as an argument, I get a `<unresolved overloaded function type>` error.

```
return unseq_invoke(std::find, view.begin(), view.end(), 0) == view.end();
```

```
main.cpp: In function ‘constexpr bool is_valid_c_str(std::string_view)’:
main.cpp:21:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘unseq_invoke(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::basic_string_view<char>::const_iterator, std::basic_string_view<char>::const_iterator, int)’
   21 |     return unseq_invoke(std::find, view.begin(), view.end(), 0) == view.end();
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:6:26: note: candidate: ‘template<class Fn, class ... T> constexpr decltype(auto) unseq_invoke(Fn&&, T&& ...)’
    6 | constexpr decltype(auto) unseq_invoke(Fn&& fn, T&& ... v) {
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:6:26: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:21:24: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Fn’
   21 |     return unseq_invoke(std::find, view.begin(), view.end(), 0) == view.end();
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Of course, I could shorten that with a macro, but it would still be an explicit wrapper, and I don't like to use macros either.

Is there a way to make `unseq_invoke(std::algorithm, ...)` work without a wrapper around `std::algorithm`? Of course, an alternative approach to mine would also help me.

Comment: I think using macro is the most appropriate way in such a case.

Comment: If you could do it without a macro I think [`BOOST_HOF_LIFT`](https://boost-hof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/include/boost/hof/lift.html) would use that

Comment: If you remove the explicit template parameters from lambda, you'll at least get a simpler wrapping: `unseq_invoke([](auto&& ...x){return std::find(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...);}, ...);` but that's still a lot. The macro that @Caleth points, essentially expands to similar code.

Comment: Yes, probably with my current approach a macro on the call is really the best solution. In the meantime I also came across the [addressing restriction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) :-/ I hope that maybe someone has a basically alternative idea to my approach.

Comment: Unrelated to question: Calling `forward` unqualified is not a good idea. It will do ADL and is likely to prefer an overload found that way, which is definitively not what you want here. You always want to call `std::forward`. Same for `invoke`.